# why change() in constructor is not defined,it should be acessed through __proto__ link in p.__proto__?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, proto

why change() in constructor is not defined,it should be acessed through **proto** link in p.**proto**?
why change() in constructor is not defined,it should be acessed through **proto** link in p.**proto**?
why change() in constructor is not defined,it should be acessed through **proto** link in p.**proto**?
why change() in constructor is not defined,it should be acessed through **proto** link in p.**proto**?

```js
//the first change() is not defined ,why
class Person {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this)
    console.log(this.__proto__)
    // change()//output:is not define
  }
  
  change() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

var p = new Person()
Object.prototype.change = function() {
  console.log(' change in prototype')
}
change() //output:change in prototype
```

Comment: Try logging: `"change" in this.__proto__`. `change` method is indeed defined on `Person.prototype` object. It is defined as a non-enumerable property, that is why it doesn't show up when you simply log `this.__proto__`

Comment: thanks first,Yousaf! i know it works by adding 'this' to method change(),but  i want to figure out why i can't  access  change() in constructor because the p has already created and we can see the method "change()" in p.__proto__. And when in the context of p ,it calls for change(),if  it can't find it in p ,it will look for it from  p.__proto__ .and change() is really in p.__proto__. 
i know "this.chang()" should be the informal way to call a function. but i'm curious why i can't  use change() directly  cause it should make sense in theory.

Comment: _"And when in the context of p ,it calls for change()"_ - No, you are not calling `change` in the _context_ of `p`. To do that, you need to call it as `this.change()`. If you don't call it using `this`, then Javascript will look for `change` in the global scope.

Comment: thank you Yousaf,thanks for your patience !and i have deep understanding :very function should be call by a instance ,if we can't see a instance reference ,it is executed like window.change() by default in a global scope ,and window is also a instance of Object.
so in a class ,if a function wants to be executed ,it must have a instance before it in case it searchs it from the global scope .

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it with this keyword.

```js
    //the first change() is not defined ,why
class Person
   {
       constructor()
       {
           console.log(this)
           console.log(this.__proto__)
           this.change()//output:is not define
       }
       change()
       {
           console.log(this)
       }

   }
 
    var p =new Person()
    Object.prototype.change=function()
    {
        console.log(' change in prototype')
    }
    change()//output:change in prototype
```

Comment: thanks first,Erenn! i know it works by adding 'this' to method change(),but  i want to figure out why i can't  access  change() in constructor because the p has already created and we can see the method "change()" in p.__proto__. And when in the context of p ,it calls for change(),if  it can't find it in p ,it will look for it from  p.__proto__ .and change() is really in p.__proto__. 
i know "this.chang()" should be the informal way to call a function. but i'm curious why i can't  use change() directly  cause it should make sense in theory.